# To do List remove text?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hey everyone I am working on developing TO DO App, got a little barrier 
When I press add button in my app the text that user input in Edit Text is store in a List View .

What I want: when user hit add button(ofCourse it will be saved in the list view that's not the problem ) the text in the edit view should remove and it will become an empty edit view then he type something and hit add, the item will be add and the edit text once again become clear

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        arrayAdapter.add(counter +" : "+ editText.getText().toString());
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        counter++ ;

        //clear the edit text 
        // editText. // i don't get the specific method that will do the job ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            arrayAdapter.add(counter +" : "+ editText.getText().toString());
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            counter++ ;

            //clear the edit text 
            editText.setText(""); // i don't get the specific method that will do the job ;


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks  . how clever you are and i was looking for method on android developers :: lol

Comment: @SaadZahoor please accept the answer if your problem is solved !!

Comment: Yeah sure !! Do it whenever it allows you to :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`editText.setText("")`

Comment: yea it helped Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you mean how to clear the editText you can simply use:

```
editText.setText("");
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine or @OmarAflak ? Please don't create duplicate answers :-)